# URLdecode with AMPScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, url-encode

Is there a way to URLdecode a URL Param with AMPscript? I am passing form data (with enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded") into landing page that should then decode the data and then write to DE. Can this be accomplish with only AMPscript?

Comment: can you post the code here?

Answer (score 2):

decodeURI() and decodeURIComponent() are JavaScript functions - not AMPScript. It's hard to tell but it looks like you're working in content builder as apposed to in cloud pages. Is that correct? You cannot save JavaScript in content builder, and also you cannot use JavaScript in an email just in case that's what you're after.

Here is an example of SSJS employing decodeURI
Source:
[image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: Ahh I see, I might have tried doing it wrong then. I was actually operating within a cloud page, but everything was inside an AMP script, i.e. no JavaScript Scripts. Is it possible to get access to a decoding function within AMPscript? The cloudpage really only serves as an endpoint to get Data into Salesforce (its not supposed to show anything).
I was testing  within an email, that is correct, but the functionality is supposed to go into a cloud page.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a decode equivalent, but I would use javascript function decodeURIComponent() (inside a freeform or html block) and then assign the value to the landing page field. If you can post your code example, it will be easier to suggest a solution.

Comment: When trying to test this, I get The subscriber preview failed to generate. Review the details, correct all issues, and try again.
An unrecognized expression appears in a script block. Script Expression: decodeURIComponent any idea how I could get the decoding to work?

Comment: @FabianBosler Can you please post a screen shot of the error and the window with the error?

Comment: see in next "answer"

Comment: decodeURIComponent() is a JavaScript function - not AMPScript. It'

Answer (score 0):

So this is not really an answer, but the only way for me to post a screenshot:

and a second one with the actual email:
[image: this produces an error]

Frankly I am not even sure, if this is the right approach, but we get stuff like this in Salesforce "D�sseldorf" and the Data comes through a webform ->  webhook -> cloudpage. And I am not quite sure where in our connection the special characters get scrambled up.

Answer (score 0):

Encode on the landing page or email:

```
%%[
      SET @queryStringPart2 = EncryptSymmetric("USE_ENCRYPTION_OF_CHOICE",  &emailAddress=test@test.com&id=123", "etcetera")
      SET @newLink = Concat("http://pages.exacttarget.com/page.aspx?QS=773ed3059447707d9cf0f7f1ffa7a5cc", "&encrypted=", @queryStringPart2)
]%%
```

Then decode on the landing page:

```
%%[
    SET @qsPart2 = QueryParameter("encrypted") /* gets the encrypted string */)
    SET @DecryptedString = DecryptSymmetric("DECRYPTION_OF_CHOICE", @qsPart2)
/* Use Substring or regex to parse the decrypted string */

]%%
```

Hope this helps!